# What does the golden spiral converge to?

Tags: fibonacci-numbers, golden-ratio

I am looking at pictures of spirals associated with the Fibonacci sequence and the golden ratio and I am seeing several different spiral diagrams.

For example one image I saw shows the spiral with the following numbers $8, 5, 3, 2, 1, 1$.

Then another has $34, 21, 13, 8, 5, 3, 2, 1$.

So, since the Fibonacci sequence continues forever is it possible to figure out where the golden spiral converges to in an image with Fibonacci sequence of $F_n, F_{n-1}, F_{n-2}, \dots$ ?

Comment: I'm not sure whether this answers your question: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golden_spiral.

Comment: The answer you require must be the limit of the recurrence relation for the Fibonacci sequence.

Comment: What do you mean that the sequence converges to?  The Fibonacci sequence is usually done in the opposite direction and diverges to infinity.  Changes at the end (in your order) or the beginning (in the usual order) do not change where it converges to in the usual order.  It looks like your second source (what is it?) missed one of the $1$s.

Answer (score 1):

The Fibonacci sequence usually begins $0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, \ldots$  with $F_0 = 0$. The sequences above are this in reverse. The second one excludes $F_1$. It seems that $F_n$ where $n < 0$ are being excluded and you are asking for the coordinates of the the start of the spiral at $F_1$. That depends on the diagram, and the coordinate system. In general, the coordinates can be found.

Answer (score 1):

https://downloads.hindawi.com/journals/ddns/2019/3149602.pdf

I had this question too and this is a paper on it I came across. It gives (5-√5)/10 multiplied by the proportions of each side. This paper uses some weird math however using the relation that φ-1=1/φ and defines λ as 1/φ so a lot of the math is given by the inverse of the golden ratio in terms of λ.